# EmberJS - sharing a controller / template for different routes

Tags: ember.js

I have a very simple CRUD application that allows for creating new objects as well as editing them.

The template used for adding a record and editing a record are almost identical.

They use the exact same form elements.
The only difference is the title and the button below the form (that should either update or create a record)

In my implementation, I have

- 2 route definitions
- 2 route objects
- 2 controller objects
- 2 templates

I was wondering if

- I can't promote re-use here
- if all of these objects are required.

What bothers me :

- I have 2 separate templates for create and edit (while they are almost identical)
- I have 2 separate controllers that do exactly the same thing.

I was hoping to solve this on the controller level. 
As a controller decorates a model, in my case 1 single controller object could wrap either a new record or an existing record.
It could then expose a property (isNewObject) so that the template can decide if we are in the "new" or "edit" flow. The controller could have a single createOrUpdate method that works both in the `new` and in the `update` scenario.

### Routes

The current implementation is using a new and an edit route for my resource.

```
this.resource("locations", function(){
  this.route("new", {path:"/new"});
  this.route("edit", {path: "/:location_id" });
});
```

#### The new route

The `new route` is responsible for creating a new record and is called when the user navigates to the new record screen.

```
App.LocationsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Location.createRecord();
  }
});
```

#### The edit route

The `edit route` is responsible for editing an existing object when the user clicks the edit button in the overview screen.
I haven't extended the default edit route but instead I'm using the auto generated one.

### Controllers

The `new` and `edit` controllers are responsible for handling the action that occurs in the template (either saving or updating a record)

The only thing both controllers do is commit the transaction.

**Note:** I guess this is a candidate for re-use, but how can I use a single controller for driving 2 different routes / templates ?

```
App.LocationsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  addItem: function(location) {
    location.transaction.commit();
    this.get("target").transitionTo("locations");
  }
});

App.LocationsEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  updateItem: function(location) {
    location.transaction.commit();
    this.get("target").transitionTo("locations");
  }
});
```

### Templates :

As you can see, the only code-reuse I have here is the partial (the model field binding).
I still have 2 controllers (new and edit) and 2 templates.

The new templates sets the correct title / button and re-uses the form partial.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="locations/new" >
    <h1>New location</h1>
    {{partial "locationForm"}}
    <p><button {{action addItem this}}>Add record</button></p>
</script>
```

The edit templates sets the correct title / button and re-uses the form partial.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="locations/edit" >
    <h1>Edit location</h1>
    {{partial "locationForm"}}
    <p><button {{action updateItem this}}>Update record</button></p>
</script>
```

The partial

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_locationForm" >
  <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="latitude">Latitude</label>
    <div class="controls">
      {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="latitude"}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="latitude">Longitude</label>
    <div class="controls">
      {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="longitude"}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="accuracy">Accuracy</label>
    <div class="controls">
      {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="accuracy"}}
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</script>
```

**Note:** I  would expect that I can do something efficient/smarter here.

I would want my template to look this this : (getting the title from the controller, and have a single action that handles both the update and the create)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="locations" >
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    {{partial "locationForm"}}
    <p><button {{action createOrUpdateItem this}}>Add record</button></p>
</script>
```

### Question

Can I re-work this code to have more code-reuse, or is it a bad idea to attempt to do this with a single template and a single controller for both the "edit record" and "new record" flows. 
If so, how can this be done ? I'm missing the part where my 2 routes (create and edit) would re-use the same controller / template.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You were correct throughout.

And you can use the new controller and template in `edit route` also.

You have to do only two things.

First give the template name as new in the `renderTemplate` hook of `edit route`.

```
App.LocationsEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('locations.new').setProperties({isNew:false,content:model});
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('locations/new')         
  }
});
```

As the new template is rendered the controller also will be `newController`, and you can have the action to point to an event in the `newController`.

If you want to change the title and button text, you can have them as computed properties observing `isNew` property.

Hope this helps.

P.S: Don't forget to set the isNew property to true in the `setupController` of `new route`

Comment: great ! Seems to work fine ... 1 small mistake in your setProperties call I guess ... had to pass a single JSON structure embedding all properties I wanted to update: setProperties({isNew:false,content:model}

Comment: Excellent Q&A! If requiring a route of the same name across resources, try this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923942/how-do-i-disambiguate-nested-routes-in-ember-js

Comment: How can i use the same controller but a different template like edit in this case? My templates are 70% same but would like to keep them separate, but i can use the same controller and can check in them, which data to load depending upon the template.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
App.YourNewRoute = Em.Route.extend ({
   controllerName: 'controllerName',
   templateName: 'templateName'
 });
```

Only use initial name like for homeController user "home" thats it.

Example:

```
App.YourNewRoute =  Em.Route.extend ({
   controllerName: 'home',
   templateName: 'home'
});
```

Now you can use template and controller methods of "home".

Comment: Thanks for adding answers, although this may work, it is slightly antiquated, a better approach now would be to componentize the template and code.